# What are the bosses of Dota autochess?

Tags: dota-autochess

Every five rounds, you play against some mobs.

Is there a list of what mobs these are? Like Round X, Roshan or things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoChess/comments/bc5bvx/is_there_a_list_of_creep_rounds/eknwswd/):

(These names will vary based on which version of this game you are playing)

10 - Golems

15 - Wolves

20 - Hellbears

25 - Wildwing

30 - Thunderhides

35 - Black Dragon

40 - Trolls

45 - ? (redditor guesses year beast)

50 - Roshan

After 50 every player takes damage every round